# PM2 Server don't start

Tags: node.js, server, cpanel, pm2, bluehost

When I try to start the pm2 server via SSH connection pm2 command never executes and just stops after PM2 Done, but the server never runs.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYbCi.png

What can be a problem in this case? I tried a lot of things but nothing works for me.

I tried other solutions like foreverjs but when I close ssh terminal the server is dying. I think only PM2 can help me to run a server in the background after close ssh terminal in Cpanel on Bluehost.

Update 1: If I break the start command when it gets noting after PM2 Done
https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0LH6.png

If I do not break the start command it just will continue maybe forever and the server never starts
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNos9.png

Command to start the server: pm2 start main.js

Comment: Don't use `--watch` and try running `pm2 ls` after the `[PM2] Done` message

Comment: Try also `pm2 logs` and add the results to your question

Comment: How to start your project?? Show me the command, add photo to the question